# Family sci-fi movie with cool jets stored under their big fancy house

Tags: story-identification, movie

Saw this film when I was little (around 2000-2006).

All I can remember is that it’s a family movie and either the dad or the whole entire family fly their own jet/spaceship like thing. They are stored under their big fancy house.

Answer (score 7):

The plot elements you describe are highly reminiscent of Thunderbirds. There was a live action film in 2004 and I suggest that this is what you are recalling. Take a look at this website for the film which includes trailers and see if it jogs your memory.

https://www.thunderbirdsmovie.com